# Stack Level too Deep in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning ROR for which I have Rails 3.
I have this following controller's action

```
def create
@album=Album.new
@album.title='Aftermath'
@album.artist='The Rolling Stones'
@album.release_date='1966/01/01 12:00:00'
@album.genre='Rock'
@album.save() #save!() doesno't event work
#render(:action => 'show_album' )
```

end
when i call this in the browser it throws exception 
**stack level too deep**

```
TinyTds::Error: Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @@TRANCOUNT'
```

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10823ms

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive             
Server operation with results pending: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @@TRANCOUNT'):
app/controllers/public_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

What is this i am missing or not covering please guide.

Comment: Check your callbacks: do you save in one of them?

Comment: Which callbacks you are talking about. I am new to ROR.

Comment: Your code is really, really wrong - I know you're new to Rails, so I'll write a post for you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you're trying to save an entry & you're getting the `Stack Level Too Deep` error

This error basically means your application is running out of memory, and it's down to your code I think. Here's what I would do:

**Creating A Record**

```
def create
    @album = Album.create(:title => "Aftermath", :artist => "The Rolling Stones", :release_date => "1966/01/01 12:00:00", :genre => "Rock")
end
```

That's if you're not receiving the data from a form

---

**Receiving Form Data**

If you are receiving data from a web form, I'd do this:

```
#app/controllers/albums_controller.rb
def new
    @album = Album.new
end

def create
    @album = Album.new(album_params)
    @album.save
end

private
def album_params
    params.require(:album).params(:title, :artist, :release_date, :genre)
end



  #app/views/albums/new.html.erb
   <%= form_for @album do |f| $>
       <%= f.text_field :title %>
       <%= f.text_field :artist %>
       <%= f.select :release_date %> -> this needs to change
       <%= f.select :genre %>  -> this needs to change
       <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: I deleted the answer, and then looked up about Stack Level Too Deep errors in Rails again, and found it's caused by an infinite recursive loop -- which, to me, sounds like a lack of memory

Comment: From what I understand, the `Stack Level Too Deep` error is basically the ["Stack Overflow"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) error, which is: "The call stack may consist of a limited amount of address space, often determined at the start of the program. The size of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of available memory"

Comment: Infinite loop is the issue, whatever your memory it will fail: memory is not the issue.

Comment: Would you prefer I change my answer?

Comment: I dont care. Its wrong but we cant help the guy since we dont see the source

Comment: I'll leave it for now. His "create" code is not correct, which I hope I have addressed, and I suppose he will receive the stack level too deep error for another issue. Thanks for showing me Stack Level Too Deep means an infinite loop

Comment: Still having the same error even after trying saving the static values via Album.create() method.

Comment: It'll be a problem in another part of your app then most likely -- do you have any other code which could be causing a problem?

Comment: There are other action in the controller but I am invoking this action which is causing the problem. Does it have anything related with any gem that i need to update or put in the gem file in the project.

Comment: What's the adaptive server you've included? This looks to be the root of the errors, except I've not had experience with such a thing

Comment: Activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.2.12

Comment: When I ran my code in my office. It worked absolutely fine. Probably something is wrong with rubymine in my laptop.